# Fit model function out defined data range

Tags: python, function, scipy, data-fitting

Let's say I have a set of data `(x=times,y=observation)` that have multiple gaps in time. Whatever is the data trend, let's assume it linear for this discussion. During the gaps in time, there is a decay that makes data deviate from the purely linear trend, until observations start again and the linear trend is recovered. *There are multiple gaps in time*, but in this example I have reported only the shortest snap to illustrate the problem. The gaps in time are times between the (positive) linear trends where there are no observations available, therefore *the difference between consecutive `x=times`* is (much) larger than, let's say, the average. I want to model the decay as part of the function (`y_decay = C -D*x`)

```
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def f(x, A, B, C, D):
    line = A*x + B if ((x>=1) & (x<=3) | (x>=5) & (x<=9) | (x>=23) & (x<=25)) else C-D*x
    return line

x=[1,2,3, 12,13,14, 23,24,25]
y=[2,4,6, 5, 7, 9, 8, 10,12]
popt, pcov = curve_fit(f, x, y) 

figure = plt.figure(figsize=(5.15, 5.15))
figure.clf()
plot = plt.subplot(111)
ax1 = plt.gca()

plot.scatter(x,y)
plt.show()
```

[image]

How do I model the `decay` variable as part of the function and obtain its best-fit value?

Comment: This not really a Python or programming question, but more of a math / modelling question. I think I understand what you're asking, but I think the answer is "it depends" but whatever the answer is, coding it could be fairly straightforward?

Comment: @Grismar I don't understand. Is it straightforward to code it, or it isn't even a programming question? The question is clear and supported by code and image, the downvote is simply unfair.

Comment: It's not a programming question, since you're not having trouble to code a solution you have in mind, but you seem to be asking how to deal mathematically with a gap in your data and how to model decay as part of the function describing your data - which is more of a math and modelling question. If you were here asking how to code that function because you were having trouble doing so, it would be a programming question. Perhaps you already know how the solution should work, you just don't know how to code it? In that case, share your thoughts and why you are having trouble coding it.

Comment: @Grismar, my issue is not how to model the decay, rather I do not know how to implement the function that models a certain model when there are data, and another model when there are no data - thus obtaining the best-fit parameters of both parts. I have edited the question to make it clearer.

Comment: Here is already a problem....what does it mean "when there is no data". On the real number line there is infinite amount of no data between your data points. So either you provide hard limits to what the no data region is or you give a model capable of fitting this. If you have an idea which one it is, try to edit the question. (Note, upon according improvement, most people a willing to remove down votes)

Comment: For what its worth, you could try a function of type `x * ( x - 1 ) * ( x + 1 ) / ( 1 + x**2 )` assuming that the slope is the same on the left and on the right.

Comment: @mikuszefski, I edited the original post to make clearer what I mean by "times where there is no data". Your function does not allow to get the best-fit slope for the decay part, which also was part of my original question and that actually brings up my incapacity to code the problem. If I misunderstood what you mean, please consider to write an answer.

Comment: is the slope of all data the same? are all decay slopes expected to be the same?

Comment: Do you know the gaps, I mean the number, or do you have to fit this as well. If so, is there other info to use, e.g.: is the gap always significantly larger than the space between data points? Or is it assured that the delta of two data points is always positive, while a gap always leads to a negative delta?

Comment: @mikuszefski, I am going to verify your answer soon, but first I'll reply to your questions. The gap is always larger than the sampling. The gap is periodic (i.e. it happens every x unit of time) but not always of the same length (because data sampling is variable). The slope is always the same. I am not sure what you mean by "delta".

Comment: By delta I mean the y difference of two data point. One might think of a situation where the noise is so large that even though the slope is positive the delta of two consecutive points is actually negative.

Comment: ...but if this is actually periodic there might be a different approach. I see that real gap distances might change if periodicity does not fall properly into sampling rate. But may I then assume that in theory duration of positive and negative slope is always the same?

Comment: @mikuszefski, yes. we can assume the slopes to stay the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With full periodicity I'd do something like this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import leastsq

def data_func( x, x0, a, bc, off, p1, p2):
    """
    fit function that uses modulus to get periodicity
    two linear functions are combines piecewise by boxing them
    using the heaviside function with the periodic input
    over all slope is added.
    Note that the "decay" part maybe positive with this solution.
    """
    P1 = abs(p1)
    P2 = abs(p2)
    X = x - x0
    P= P1 + P2
    mod = X % P
    y0 = a * P1
    beta = y0 * P / P2
    slope = y0 / P2
    box1 =  np.heaviside( +np.abs( ( X - P1 / 2. ) % P - 0.5 * P ) - 0.5 * P2, .5 )
    box2 =  np.heaviside( -np.abs( ( X - P1 / 2. ) % P - 0.5 * P ) + 0.5 * P2, .5 )
    out = a * mod * box1 
    out += (beta - slope * mod  )* box2
    out += off + bc * X
    return out


def residuals( params, xl ,yl ):
    x0, a, bc, off, p1, p2 = params
    diff = np.fromiter( ( y - data_func( x, x0, a, bc, off, p1, p2 ) for x, y in zip( xl, yl )  ), np.float )
    return diff



theOff = 0.7
theP1= 1.8869
theP2 = 5.21163
theP = theP1 + theP2
xdata = np.linspace(-1, 26, 51 )
xdata = np.fromiter( ( x for x in xdata if (x-theOff)%theP <= theP1 ),np.float )
ydata = np.fromiter( ( data_func( x, theOff, .6, .1, 17, theP1, theP2) for x in xdata ),np.float )

tl = np.linspace(-1, 26, 150 )
yl = np.fromiter( ( data_func( x, theOff, .6, .1, 17, theP1, theP2) for x in tl ),np.float )

guess= [0, 0.55, .1, 16 , 2, 5 ]
sol, err = leastsq( residuals, guess, args = ( xdata, ydata ) )
print sol
### getting the real slopes out of the data
s1 = sol[1]+ sol[2] 
s2 =  - sol[1] * sol[4] / sol[5] + sol[2]
print "real slope1 = {}".format( s1 )
print "real slope2 = {}".format( s2 )

fit = np.fromiter( ( data_func( x, *sol ) for x in tl ),np.float )
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot( 1, 1, 1 )

### original data
ax.plot( tl, yl, ls='--')
ax.plot( xdata, ydata, ls='', marker='+')
### fit
ax.plot( tl, fit )

### check the slopes
short = np.linspace(0, 3, 3)
ax.plot( short, [ 17 + s1 * s for s in short ] )
short = np.linspace(3, 10, 3)
ax.plot( short, [ 18 + s2 * s for s in short ] )

ax.grid()
plt.show()
```

which gives:

```
>> [ 0.39352332  0.59149625  0.10850375 16.78546632  1.85009228  5.35049099]
>> real slope1 = 0.7
>> real slope2 = -0.0960237685357
```

and

[image: periodic linear]

Naturally, the lack of information in the gaps results in a rather bad fit of the slope there. As a consequence there is an according error in the periodicity. If that would be known, the accuracy would increase of course.

You need a reasonable good guess for the starting parameters!

Answer (score 0):

That would be my Ansatz when assuming that all data has the same slope `m` and all "decay" the slope `D`

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt ### only for plotting; not important for the OP
import numpy as np ### for easy data manipulation
from scipy.optimize import leastsq ### one of many possibilities for optimization

def generic_data( m, D, n ): ### just generating data; not important for OP
    alpha0 = 0
    timel = [ 0 ] ### to avoid errer, remove at the end
    dl = list()
    for gaps in range( n + 1 ): 
        for pnts in range( 3 + np.random.randint( 2 ) ): 
            timel.append ( timel[-1] +  0.5 + np.random.rand() )
            dl.append( m * timel[ -1 ] + alpha0 )
        ###now the gap
        dt =  2. + 2 * np.random.rand()
        timel.append ( timel[-1] + dt )
        dl.append( dl[-1] - D * dt )
        alpha0 = dl[-1] - m * timel[-1]
    del timel[0]
    ### remove jump of last gap
    del timel[-1]
    del dl[-1]
    dl = np.fromiter( ( y + np.random.normal( scale=0.1 ) for y in dl ), np.float )
    return np.array( timel ), dl

def split_into_blocks( tl, dl ):
    """
    identifying the data blocks by detecting positions of negative slope.
    first subtract a shifted version of the data from itself
    find the negatives and get their positions
    get sub-lists based on this positins 
    """
    mask = np.where( dl[1::] - dl[:-1:] < 0, 1, 0 )
    where = np.argwhere( mask )
    where = where.reshape( 1, len( where ) )[0]
    where = np.append( where, len( dl ) - 1 )
    where = np.insert( where, 0, -1 )
    tll = list()
    dll = list()
    for s, e in zip( where[ :-1:], where[ 1:: ] ):
        dll.append( dl[ s + 1 : e + 1 ] )
        tll.append( tl[ s + 1 : e + 1 ] )
    return np.array( tll ), np.array( dll )



def residuals( params, tblocks, dblocks ):
    """
    typical residual function to be called by leastsq
    """
    ### split parameters
    nob = len( tblocks )
    m = params[0] ### all data with same slope
    D = params[1] ### all decay with same slope
    alphal = params[2:2+nob] ### off sets differ
    betal = params[-nob+1::]
    out = list()
    ### evaluate diefference between data and test function
    for i, (tl, dl) in enumerate( zip(tblocks, dblocks ) ):
        diff = [ d - ( m * t + alphal[i] ) for t, d in zip( tl, dl ) ]
        out= out + diff
    ### evaluate differences for the gapfunction; this could be done
    ### completely independent, but I do it here to have all in one shot.
    for j in range( nob -1 ):
        out.append( dblocks[ j][-1] - ( betal[j] + D * tblocks[j][-1] ) ) ###left point gap
        out.append( dblocks[ j+1][0] - ( betal[j] + D * tblocks[j+1][0] ) ) ###right point gap
    return out

### create generic data
tl, dl =  generic_data( 1.3, .3, 3 )
tll, dll = split_into_blocks( tl, dl )

### and fit
nob = len(dll)
m0 = +1.0
D0 = -0.1
guess = [m0, D0 ]+ nob * [-3] + ( nob - 1 ) * [ +4 ]
sol, err = leastsq( residuals, x0=guess, args=( tll, dll ) )

mf = sol[0]
Df = sol[1]

print mf, Df
alphal = sol[2:2+nob]
betal = sol[-nob+1::]

### ... and plot
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot( 1, 1, 1 )

###original data
ax.plot( tl, dl, ls='', marker='o')
###identify blocks
for a,b in zip( tll, dll ):
    ax.plot( a, b, ls='', marker='x')
###fit results
for j in range(nob):
    tloc = np.linspace( tll[j][0] - 0.3, tll[j][-1] + 0.3 , 3 )
    ax.plot( tloc, [ mf * t + alphal[j] for t in tloc ] )
for j in range(nob - 1):
    tloc = np.linspace( tll[j][-1] - 0.3, tll[j+1][0] + 0.3 , 3 )
    ax.plot( tloc, [ Df * t +betal[j] for t in tloc ] )
plt.show()
```

This the results in

```
>> 1.2864142170851447 -0.2818180721270913
```

and

[image: some fitted test data]

The model, however, might require that the decay line does not cross the data line within the data range. This makes additional fiddling necessary as the we need to check some type of boundaries. On the other hand one could just fit the data and look for the decay curves with the smallest possible slope fulfilling the previously mentioned boundary. In this case, hence, I'd drop the `D` fitting part from the residuals and calculate it later.

Comment: Could you comment your code a bit? I do not know many modules and it is a bit hard to follow to me